# ArcMap minimum bounding geometry around groups of lines massive spike stretching far into the distance

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, boundaries

ArcMap 10.4.0.5524 for Desktop. No internet connection.

I have a bunch of lines that represent roads. I would like to make convex hulls to isolate groups of these roads. When I do this in ArcMap, a rectangle works, but choosing the convex hull option results in a huge spike stretching far off into the distance. I have exhausted the available internet resources, which mainly consists of this thread ([link](https://community.esri.com/t5/data-management-questions/the-results-of-minimum-bounding-geometry-stretches/td-p/66766)). What on earth is going on?

I already tried repairing the geometry, it did not resolve the issue.

The lines are in GCS_North_American_1983

I tried the Integrate tool, but it did not help.

Comment: I already tried that, I should have put that in the post originally. It did not work.

Comment: Try [Integrate](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/integrate.htm), but backup your data first, the tool will modify it

Comment: Without any details on data, projection, or procedures, it unlikely anyone will be able to tell. The terminal 10.4 release was 10.4.1, and 10.5.1, 10.6.1, 10.7.1, and 10.8.1 have followed (not to mention all the Pro snapshots), so there isn't much reason for any fix to be forthcoming, even if this were reported.

Comment: @BERA I tried Integrate as well but it did not change anything.

Comment: When you tried to fix it, what was environment extent set to?

Comment: @FelixIP I don't know how to answer this question! What does that mean?

Comment: Environment extent can be default,  union of inputs etc. This is the thing to check, when I see unexpected results.

Comment: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/environments/setting-geoprocessing-environment.htm